# Should I make a generic “Is my homebrew game content balanced?” Question with an Answer of “Probably not, No”?

Tags: discussion, homebrew, community-wiki

Something that I’ve noticed happening over and over again is a new user showing up with a homebrew piece of game content (e.g. a race, class, feat, et cetera), and then posting a Question to the effect of “Is my thing balanced” which almost always has an Answer of “No, it isn’t.”

It’s to the point where I’m considering posting a Question of my own that’s a generic version of the question with a self-Answer of “No, it probably isn’t’” with an explanation of why that’s likely the case (professional game designers do it for a living and have more experience, their designs often include hidden assumptions about how things are structured, they sometimes utilise community feedback cycles to test things, etc).

That way whenever one of these questions get asked, we can just link to the general case in the Comments. I think that they’re called a Community Wiki entry?

Comment: Related: [Are we satisfied with the state of homebrew review questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9096/are-we-satisfied-with-the-state-of-homebrew-review-questions), [What rules/guidance do we want to give for homebrew review questions, if any?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9148/what-rules-guidance-do-we-want-to-give-for-homebrew-review-questions-if-any), [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-can-i-ask-a-good-homebrew-review-question)

Comment: (I upvoted this question because I think it's a good question despite me also thinking it's a bad idea. Folks should be encouraged to ask more of these kinds of questions.)

Comment: NB [community wiki](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) is a different thing that’s unrelated to setting up a generic target for closing as duplicate.

Answer (score 25):

## That's Unfriendly and Unhelpful

We come here to solve problems. We give answers to questions that include explanations or backing. When a homebrewer asks a review question, it is implicit that 'is it balanced' should not be answered by a mere 'yes/no', but also have the *reasoning* for why something is or isn't OK. A generic answer by definition doesn't provide that.

Such a pre-emptive answer also happens to shut down people's attempts to seek a solution for their problems, even though the seeking is on-topic for the site. That's rather adversarial and shouldn't be done.

Finally, you say that 'likely no' stems from amateurs lacking the experience and resources required to achieving 'perfect' balance, but (a) by shutting down such question you are denying homebrewers such community feedback cycles and experience-gaining opportunities and (b) balance is a matter of degree, and such questions are likely to at least help the homebrewer *increase* the degree of balance if answered in detail.