# What does the author to this item rarity question need to actually do to get their question reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Concerning the question: [How rare is this artificer magic item I created?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188787/how-rare-is-this-artificer-magic-item-i-created)

This question was closed as unclear. The author has revised, and their revisions include addressing concerns in comments (such as specifying in what way the item uses a healing kit). That revision was rolled back and the question remains closed.

I suspect we're doing the author a disservice here in not making it clear what we actually expect from them.

**What does this author need to specifically do in order to get their question reopened?**

Answer (score 9):

#### In a comment, I stated explicitly what I wanted to see for my reopen vote.

I wrote a [comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188787/how-rare-is-this-artificer-magic-item-i-created#comment508592_188787) right after rolling back the edit:

> I've rolled back the edit for now, as iterations of homebrew reviews should be posted as new questions [at least 72 hours](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9151/62294) after the first posting. The details I wanted to see for reopening were answers to NautArch's two comments [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188787/how-rare-is-this-artificer-magic-item-i-created#comment508567_188787) and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188787/how-rare-is-this-artificer-magic-item-i-created#comment508566_188787)

The two comments from NautArch were:

> Are other players getting homebrew items? If so, can you let us know what those are and what rarity was assigned?

> Also, I'm not quite sure I understand the question. Are you asking what the rarity of an item that does all three is, or three separate items? I'm pretty sure it's the former, right?

I rolled back the edit because the revisions were substantive changes to the content *in response to the posted answers*, [which we have a rule against](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9151/62294). I then left a comment stating explicitly what I wanted to see out of the question before reopening. So I'm not sure this is accurate:

> I suspect we're doing the author a disservice here in not making it clear what we actually expect from them.

My comment was clear and asked explicitly for some concrete information.

Comment: More as a general reminder for folks, it's very easy for outstanding requests to be lost when it starts being a long comment thread, so it's very helpful to flag obsolete comments as No Longer Needed. I've done a compromise now (partially to not lose anything should it be important) of moving a bunch of comments to chat, which should at least help a bit.